How can one automatically check if the text in one of the pages of a PDF exceeds the page margin?
I have a PDF with 10 pages. How can one automatically check if the text in one of the pages exceeds the page margin?
Example of a page that exceeds the page margin (I added the vertical black margin to indicate the page margin):


Example of what I mean by page margin (the red rectangle shows the page margin):

I use Windows, or can use CLI on Ubuntu.

@KJ Thank you, good point, let's assume that page margins are given as input, along with the PDF.

@KJ margins thanks, one option would be expressing as a percentage. Good to know about MuPDF!

@KJ thanks, looks neat, you're welcome to add it as an answer!
